# Actualizar JTable ante un cambio en el modelo de datos

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Tengo un JDialog que actualiza los datos de un usuario y una vez que le doy al botón actualizar, valida los datos,  hace una petición PUT a un endpoint creado por mi y actualiza los datos del usuario en la base de datos. Hasta ahí todo bien.

```
    private void btnActualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        URL url;
        if (validaDatos()) {
            try {

                Object idUsuario = recuperaPersona.get("id");
                url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/usuario/" + idUsuario);

                //Preparar la información a enviar
                Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                params.put("nombre", txtNombre.getText());
                params.put("primerApellido", txtPrimerApellido.getText());
                params.put("segundoApellido", txtSegundoApellido.getText());
                params.put("calle", txtCalle.getText());
                params.put("ciudad", txtCiudad.getText());
                params.put("codigoPostal", txtCodigoPostal.getText());
                params.put("fechaAlta", sdf.format(dchFechaAlta.getDate()));
                params.put("fechaNacimiento", sdf.format(dchFechaNacimiento.getDate()));
                if (ValidadorFormulario.validarDNI(txtDni.getText())) {
                    params.put("dni", txtDni.getText());
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El DNI no es correcto");
                }
                params.put("correoElectronico", txtCorreoElectronico.getText());
                params.put("telefono", txtTelefono.getText());
                params.put("fotoUsuario", rutaDeLaFoto);

                String jsonData = gson.toJson(params);
                System.out.println(jsonData);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
                    byte[] input = jsonData.getBytes("utf-8");
                    os.write(input, 0, input.length);
                }
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paciente actualizado correctamente");
                    
                    
                    consumoApiVerPacientes.fireTableDataChanged();
                    
                    dispose();
                    
                }
                
                
                
                

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Una vez realizado esto actualizo el modelo de datos con el metodo fireTableDataChanged() con el fin de actualizar la tabla que está en el Frame padre de este JDialog. El problema es que el modelo de datos no se actualiza de este modo, quedando la tabla tal cual sin actualizar.

Este es mi modelo de datos :

```
public class ConsumoApiVerPacientes extends AbstractTableModel{
    private StringBuilder informationString;
    private JSONArray jSONArray;
    JSONObject objetoJson;

    private final String[] nombresColumnas = {"Nombre", "Primer Apellido", "Segundo Apellido", "DNI","Fecha de Nacimiento"};

    public ConsumoApiVerPacientes() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/usuarios/todos");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Ocurrió un error: " + responseCode);
            } else {
                informationString = new StringBuilder();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
                }
                scanner.close();

                jSONArray = new JSONArray(informationString.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return jSONArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int fila, int columna) {
         objetoJson = jSONArray.getJSONObject(fila);
        switch (columna) {
            case 0:
                return objetoJson.get("nombre");
            case 1:
                return objetoJson.get("primerApellido");
            case 2:
                return objetoJson.get("segundoApellido");
            case 3:
                return objetoJson.get("dni");
            case 4:
                return objetoJson.get("fechaNacimiento");
           
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int i) {
        return nombresColumnas[i];
    }
    
    public JSONObject recuperaPersona(int indiceTabla){
        return jSONArray.getJSONObject(indiceTabla);
        
        
    }
    
  
}
```

El problema creo que está en que el fireTableDatachange() no se propaga del Jdialog al elemento padre, por lo que agradecería ayuda al respecto.